# Como encontrar las funciones de un form dinamico en ASP

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

Espero me puedan ayudar, tengo una pagina con un login, que al poner los datos de inicio de sesión, me indica que falta una función de Javascript, la cual ya la agregué en el archivo Login.aspx (anexo captura de donde puse la función)

```
<%@ Page Language="c#" CodeBehind="Login.aspx.cs" AutoEventWireup="True" Inherits="PartNumberWatcher.Login" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html style="width:100%; height:100%">
    <head id="Head1" runat="server" >
        <title id="titleLogin" runat="server">Login</title>
        <meta name="description" content="GDL Framework for creating new web applications."/> 
        <meta name="GENERATOR" content="Microsoft Visual Studio .NET 7.1" />
        <meta name="CODE_LANGUAGE" content="C#" />
        <meta name="vs_defaultClientScript" content="JavaScript" />
        <meta name="vs_targetSchema" content="http://schemas.microsoft.com/intellisense/ie5" />
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="../../Images/AppIcon.ico"/>
        <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
            function fnGetElement(id) {
                return document.getElementById(id);
            }

            function fnCheckForm(typeOfTran) {
                if (!Jabil.Utils.fnValidateObject("txtUserName", texts.USER_NAME_EMPTY) || !Jabil.Utils.fnValidateObject("txtPassword", texts.PASSWORD_EMPTY) || !Jabil.Utils.fnValidateObject("cmbSite", texts.SITE_EMPTY) || !Jabil.Utils.fnValidateObject("cmbLanguage", texts.LANGUAGE_EMPTY)) {
                    return;
                }
                Jabil.Web.fnExecuteTran(typeOfTran);
            }
            function fnGo(ev) {
                if (ev.keyCode == 13) {
                    fnCheckForm(7);
                }
            }
            function fnChangeUser() {
                Jabil.Web.fnExecuteTran("8");
            }
            function fnChangeLanguage() {
                document.getElementById("txtPKLanguage").value = document.getElementById("cmbLanguage").value;
                document.getElementById("txtPKSite").value = document.getElementById("cmbSite").value;
                Jabil.Web.fnExecuteTran("");
            }
            function fnGoToIntranet() {
                window.location = "http://gdl/";
            }
        </script>

    <body style="width:100%; height:100%">
        <form id="frmLogin" method="post" runat="server" style="width:100%; height:100%;">
            <table style="width:100%; height:100%;">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <div id="divBlue" style="z-index:1; position: fixed; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 100%; height: 20px; background-color: #015289"></div>
                        <div style="width: 800px; margin:auto;">
                            <div><asp:Label ID="lblMessage" runat="server"></asp:Label></div>
                            <table style="width:100%;">
                                <tr>
                                    <td style="width:20%"></td>
                                    <td style="width:60%">
                                        <img alt="Go to intranet" title="Go to intranet" id="imgLogin" class="imgLogin" onclick="fnGoToIntranet();" src="../../Images/Logos/Jabil_cMedium.png" runat="server" />
                                    </td>
                                    <td style="width:20%; text-align:right">
                                        <img src="../../Images/Login/Key.png" style="position:relative; bottom:-95px; right:-40px;" alt="" />
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                        <table id="tblLogin" class="tblLogin" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                            <tr style="background-color:#E8EEFA; height:100%;">
                                <td style="width:50%">
                                    <table cellspacing="0" style="width: 100%;">
                                        <tr style="height: 100px">
                                            <td class="header" style="border-right: 1px solid White">
                                                <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="width:100%" border="0">
                                                    <tr style="text-align: center">
                                                        <td rowspan="2" style="width: 5%">&nbsp;</td>
                                                        <td rowspan="2" style="width: 70%;">
                                                            <label id="lblSystemName" class="systemName" runat="server">MX Solution</label>
                                                        </td>
                                                        <td style="width:15%;">
                                                            <label id="lblVersion" class="systemVersion">VERSION</label>
                                                        </td>
                                                        <td rowspan="2" style="width: 5%">&nbsp;</td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td>
                                                            <label id="lblSystemVersion" class="systemVersionNumber" runat="server">4.0.0</label>
                                                        </td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                </table>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr style="height: 180px">
                                            <td style="border-right: 1px solid gray;">
                                                <div class="divParagraph">
                                                    <p id="lblSystemDescription" class="label" runat="server">The PartNumberWatcher is a web based framework...</p>
                                                </div>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr style="height: 30px" class="trBottomLogin">
                                            <td style="border-right: 1px solid white">
                                                <label id="lblDate" runat="server">[Current Date]</label>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </table>
                                </td>
                                <td style="width:50%">
                                    <table cellspacing="0" style="width: 100%;">
                                        <tr style="height: 100px" class="header">
                                            <td colspan="4">
                                                <div >
                                                    <label id="lblTitle">- Authentication -</label>
                                                </div>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr style="height:180px; background-color:#E8EEFA;">
                                            <td>
                                                <table style="width:100%" border="0">
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td style="width: 15%">
                                                            &nbsp;
                                                        </td>
                                                        <td style="width: 25%; text-align: left;">
                                                            <label id="lblUserName" class="label">User Name</label>
                                                        </td>
                                                        <td style="width: 45%;">
                                                            <input id="txtUserName" name="txtUserName" class="input" runat="server" style="background-color:#FFF3CA; width:98%;" onkeypress="fnGo(event);" />
                                                        </td>
                                                        <td style="width: 15%">
                                                            &nbsp;
                                                        </td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td style="width: 15%">
                                                            &nbsp;
                                                        </td>
                                                        <td style="width: 25%; text-align: left;">
                                                            <label id="lblPassword" class="label">Password</label>
                                                        </td>
                                                        <td style="width: 45%;">
                                                            <input id="txtPassword" class="input" name="txtPassword" type="password" style="width:98%; background-color:#FFF3CA;" runat="server"
                                                                onkeypress="fnGo(event);" />
                                                        </td>
                                                        <td style="width: 15%">
                                                            &nbsp;
                                                        </td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td style="width: 15%">
                                                            &nbsp;
                                                        </td>
                                                        <td style="width:70%" colspan="2">
                                                            <div style="border: 1px Solid Gray; background-color: LightGrey; height: 25px; line-height: 25px" title="Using WinNT security means to login with your Windows account, not using it means login with a system account." >
                                                                &nbsp;<input id="chkWinNT" name="chkWinNT" type="checkbox" checked="checked" runat="server" />
                                                                <label id="lblWinNT" for="chkWinNT" class="label">WinNT Security</label>&nbsp;
                                                            </div>
                                                        </td>
                                                        <td style="width: 15%">
                                                            &nbsp;
                                                        </td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                    <tr><td colspan="4">&nbsp;</td></tr>
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td colspan="4" style="text-align:right">
                                                            <input id="btnLogin" name="btnLogin" style="height:30px; margin-right:16px; width:100px;" type="button" value="- Login -" onclick="fnCheckForm(7);" />&nbsp;
                                                        </td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                </table>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr style="height: 30px" class="trBottomLogin">
                                            <td>
                                                <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="width: 100%;" border="0">
                                                    <tr>
                                                        
                                                        <td style="width: 16%">
                                                            <label id="lblSite" class="label" style="color: White">Site</label>
                                                        </td>
                                                        <td style="width: 31%">
                                                            <select id="cmbSite" class=" combo" name="cmbSite" style="width: 100%;" runat="server"></select>
                                                        </td>
                                                        <td style="width: 16%">
                                                            <label id="lblLanguage" class="label" style="color: White">Language</label>
                                                        </td>
                                                        <td style="width: 31%">
                                                            <select id="cmbLanguage" class=" combo" name="cmbLanguage" style="width: 100%;" onchange="fnChangeLanguage();" runat="server"></select>
                                                        </td>
                                                        <td style="width: 6%">&nbsp;</td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                </table>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </table>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                        <div class="footerInfo">
                            <br />
                            <label style="white-space: nowrap"></label><br />
                            <span style="white-space:nowrap">
                                <label id="lblChangeUser">Problems with the Authentication, click</label>
                                <a id="lnkHereChangeUser" href="javascript:fnChangeUser();">here</a>
                            </span>
                            &nbsp;|&nbsp;
                            <span style="white-space:nowrap">
                                <label id="lblFeedBack">Send your comments/suggestions</label>
                                <a id="lnkHereMail" href="" runat="server">here</a>
                            </span>
                        </div>
                        <div style="text-align: center;">
                            <input id="txtAction" name="txtAction" type="hidden" runat="server" value="7" />
                            <input id="txtActionParams" name="txtActionParams" type="hidden" runat="server" />
                            <input id="txtPKLanguage" name="txtPKLanguage" type="hidden" runat="server" />
                            <input id="txtPKSite" name="txtPKSite" type="hidden" runat="server" />
                        </div>
                        <div id="divGreen" style="z-index:1; position: fixed; left: 0px; bottom: 0px; width: 100%; height: 20px; background-color: #018A5E"></div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

pero al momento de debuggear me manda a un archivo Login dinamico, el cual no encuentro para ver que si este correctamente la función (anexo la parte dinamica donde me menciona que no existe la función)

```
        function fnType() {
            if (fnGetElement("txtAction").value == "1") {
                fnGetElement("lblDirections").style.display = "none";
                fnGetElement("lblDirectionsRedirectFirst").style.display = "block";
                fnGetElement("lblDirectionsRedirectUser").style.display = "block";
                fnGetElement("lblDirectionsRedirectLast").style.display = "block";
            }
        }
```

Cabe destacar que la ruta que menciona ahi en el error, si la tengo completa y si estan los archivos correctos.

Espero me puedan ayudar, ya que no encuentro una solución viable, que me den consejos u opciones de lo que pueda ser.

Gracias.

Comment: Bienvendio a SOes, por favor edita la pregunta y agrega el  código como texto, en vez de imagen; incluye también el error y el código donde declaras la función.

Comment: muchas gracias la editaré en un momento

Answer (score 0):

Para el caso que muestras, lo que ocurre es que la función (que es de JavaScript) `fntGetElement` no existe, esto se debe a que como tal no se encuentra alguna que coincida (los motivos pueden ser diversos como: no ha sido declarada, algún detalle de Mayúsculas/Minúsculas con el nombre real a como los estas usando e incluso no has incluido el `js` donde está declarada).

En resumen verifica los `js` que cargas así como la forma en que esta escrita, de lo contrario pues te falta crearla.